# NavigationPage BarBackgroundColor does not work on Xamarin.Android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have XF app which gives the user an option to change from Light to Dark theme with a button click. I am using the below code:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
                    x:Class="Japanese.NavBackgroundRes">
    <Style TargetType="NavigationPage">
        <Setter Property="BarBackgroundColor" Value="{DynamicResource GridBackgroundColor}"/>
        <Setter Property="BarTextColor" Value="{DynamicResource LabelTextColor}" />
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

This works perfectly on iOS but not in Android. The `BarTextColor` property works for both iOS and Android but the `BarBackgroundColor` only works on iOS. Anyone knows why that is? I am debugging on a physical device if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

There is a concept in Android called the [Material design](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/).

Since Xamarin has adopted the Native Java Android Behavior in Xamarin.Android what happens is that the Android application picks the theme in its styles.xml file and uses that style to set the bar background colour.

But of course, there is a workaround. Whatever changes that you need to do on the Android side you will have to update it in the style file for it for eg:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
 <resources>
 <style name="MyTheme" parent="MyTheme.Base">
   </style>

 <style name="DrawerArrowStyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle">
 <item name="spinBars">true</item>
 <item name="color">#FFFFFF</item>
 </style>

 <style name="MyTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
 <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
 <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
 <item name="colorPrimary">#003399</item>
 <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#003399</item>
 <item name="colorControlHighlight">#003399</item>
 <item name="colorAccent">#012348</item>
 <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>
 </style>

 </resources>
```

A change in colour here will directly reflect there, for eg ColorPrimary is your toolbar background colour (BarBackgroundColor).

**UPDATE**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:id="@+id/toolbar"
 android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
 android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
 app:theme="@style/ToolbarTheme" >
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Then get the toolbar something like this:

```
var toolbar=yourActivityContext.Window.DecorView.FindViewById<Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbar);
toolbar.SetBackgroundColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Your_Color);
//In case of hex color 
toolbar.SetBackgroundColor(Android.Graphics.Color.ParseColor("#ebebeb"));
```

Comment: I am familiar with changing the navigation bar color in `style.xml` file. But as far as I know doing it this way would only allow the changes of color once, meaning I can't switch from dark to light with a button click unless I am missing something.

Comment: Well actually the problem is that this a bug with Xamarin currently and i haven't if they are resolving it or not but this issue is something that i have been facing for a while now secondly if you want to dynamically change the toolbar color that is possible using a dependency service as of now

Answer (score 0):

Use BackgroundColor instead of BarBackgroundColor for android.

use both properties for android and iphone.

```
<NavigationPage BarBackgroundColor="#F05123" BackgroundColor="#F05123" BarTextColor="White" >
```